# How to know if the month I am in coincides with a date

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I need to validate, if the current month matches a month of a saved date (a date of birth)

Example:

Date 11/25/2020

Date of birth: 03/30/1999

In this case it is false

Any ideas?

This is a example for my data:

```
_id: ObjectId("5fb72a4245494b99847d63c2")
name: "Jose Angel Colin Najera"
age: 21
birthdate: 1999-03-19T06:00:00.000+00:00
```

Example in JASON

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5fbeaab200318b85c4d8c267"
    },
    "name": "Jose Angel Colin Najera",
    "age": {
        "$numberDecimal": "21"
    },
    "birthdate": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "921823200000"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: include sample document to see the exact format of dates etc

Comment: Ready, I modified the question adding the requested